# Slick 3.0.1 limit connections to db

Tags: postgresql, slick-3.0

I'm looking at doing something as simple as limiting the number of connections that Slick 3.0.1 has to a postgres db.

This doesn't work since after a while the number of connections goes to 18 for example.

```
source-db = {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://..."
    user = "..."
    password = "..."
  }
  numThreads = 1 
  maxConnections = 5
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a play application you are probably using [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). To change the settings you need to add something like this to the configuration:

```
  hikaricp {
    minimumIdle = 2
    maximumPoolSize = 5
  }
```

Comment: I'm not using Play but I do use HikariCP. Thank you for the help!